# Multiple annotations found at this line: - Can not find the tag directory "/WEB- INF/tags/"

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

Below is my include.jsp file-

```
<%@ page session="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" %>
```

I have an error

> Can not find the tag directory “/WEB- INF/tags/”

Comment: maybe you don't have tags directory in your WEB-INF folder

Comment: @Vaibhav chavan show your web.xml

Answer (score 0):

It's because of one of the following reasons:

- No prefix mentioned : `<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="x" %>`
- Not mentioned version info in web-app tag

  ```
  <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
   version="2.4">`
  ```
- No `jstl jar` or `standard jar`